# Calling a procedure inside a procedure with independent sessions

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to call a procedure inside a procedure but this gives me an error like:

```
Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 19 at position 2 : This session warehouse WH_STD_EDWQA_ANALYST no longer exists.
```

My parent procedure construct is like creating a warehouse & the child procedure is to populate a metadata table(custom) by use of `table(result_scan(last_query_id()))`.

Parent procedure construct:

```
create or replace procedure wh_resource_govern(type varchar, env varchar, ..., varchar)
returns varchar not null
language sql
as
$$
declare
  wh_name   varchar;
  wh_setup  varchar;
  lv_acct_name varchar;
begin
  wh_name  := 'WH_' || type || '_' || env || '_' || team;
  wh_setup := 'CREATE OR REPLACE WAREHOUSE' || ' ' || wh_name || ' ' || 'WITH' || ' '
              || 'WAREHOUSE_SIZE = ' || v_wh_size || ' '
              ...,
              || 'COMMENT= '|| '"' || v_created_by || '"' ;
  execute immediate wh_setup;
  commit;
  call load_all_warehouse_metadata('a', 'b', 'c');          ----> This is where it is getting stuck.
end;
$$
;
```

Child procedure construct is given as below:

```
create or replace procedure load_all_warehouse_metadata(wh_type varchar, wh_env varchar, wh_team varchar)
returns varchar not null
language sql
as
$$
declare
  lv_acct_name   varchar;
begin
  select current_account() into lv_acct_name;
  show warehouses;
  insert into ALL_WAREHOUSE_METADATA (account_name, warehouse_type, .., .., ) 
  select :lv_acct_name, :wh_type, :wh_env,  :wh_team, "name", ..., ..., 
  from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));
end;
$$
;
```

Any inputs on how to address this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a warehouse immediately makes it the current warehouse for the session, example:

```
create or replace warehouse FOO;
select current_warehouse(); -- FOO
drop warehouse FOO();
select current_warehouse(); -- NULL
```

When you run `execute immediate wh_setup;` in the first SP, it's setting the session's warehouse to the one you just created. Calling a child SP using owner's rights (default) from a warehouse that isn't the one that started the SP is causing context problems for the warehouse.

You can reproduce this error as follows:

```
create or replace procedure SP1()
returns varchar not null
language sql
--execute as caller
as
$$
declare
    currentWarehouse varchar;
begin
    select current_warehouse() into currentWarehouse;
    create or replace warehouse FOO;
    call SP2();
    return currentWarehouse;
end;
$$;

create or replace procedure SP2()
returns varchar not null
language sql
--execute as caller
as
$$
declare
    currentWarehouse varchar;
begin
    select current_warehouse() into currentWarehouse;
    create or replace temp table FOO(s string);
    insert into FOO(S) values ('Bar');
    return 'Done';
end;
$$;

call SP1();
```

You can fix this code sample immediately by uncommenting the two commented-out ownership options for SP1 and SP2:

`--execute as caller` (Remove the comment markers and recreate both SPs.)

You can also run a SQL command to `use warehouse <wh_name>` in your SP(s), but you must run the SP as caller in order to change warehouse context this way.

Comment: Thank you Greg for the inputs. It helped !!